# Set an out-of-office message in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

How do I make the out-of-office option visible in Lotus Notes?

It was usually available under the Tools drop down but now only Preferences is visible under this drop-down.

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To enable out-of-office notification

1. Open your mail (if it's not already open).
2. Above the message list, click More → Out of Office...

[image: Screenshot of Lotus Notes e-mail client with the proper menu items being selected.]

Comment: Nice answer, easily identifiable.Up voted .